# ¿Cómo detectar cuando ocurra una acción en un nodo de un JTree y además agregarle un evento?

Tags: java, java-swing

He estado estudianto los JTree de Java, pero tengo una pregunta: ¿cómo puedo detectar cuando ocurra una acción en un nodo y además agregarle un evento?

Ya sé cómo crear un árbol con toda su estructura, nodos, hijos, qué clases debo importar, etc.

Answer (score 0):

No sé muy bien si te refieres a eventos de cambio de datos en el modelo del JTree o eventso visuales como selección, expansión de nodos, clicks.

Si quieres enterarte cuando se añaden, cambien o eliminen nodos, añade listeners al modelo DefaultTreeModel usando el método addTreeModelListener(). Cuando hagas cambios en el modelo, llama a los métodos fire*() que tiene esa clase, esto avisará de los cambios a los que se hayan suscrito.

Si quieres enterarte de cosas que pasan en la parte visual del JTree, usa los métodos de JTree addTreeExpansionListener() para expansión/compresión de nodos, addTreeSelectionListener() para selección de nodos o addMouseListener() para clicks en nodos. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html

Se bueno.

Comment: gracias, me refiero a cuando se da click en un nodo sin hijos, nodo hoja